# The glasses were too thick for her to see well (in/with)?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

1. The glasses were so thick that she couldn't see well with them.
2. The glasses were so thick that she couldn't see well in them.
3. The glasses were too thick for her to see well.
4. The glasses were too thick for her to see well with.
5. The glasses were too thick for her to see well in.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Pity this got closed. The OP is, after all, a new contributor. @happy, I'm not exactly sure why it got closed ("off topic" doesn't seem to fit) but I suspect it might be simply that there isn't much *to* your question. For example, you don't say *why* you are wondering if some of the sentences might be incorrect? What made you ask the question in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

They're all fine grammatically and they all mean pretty much the same thing.

If I had to choose a preference, it would be 1, with 4 a close second (apparently I feel that when it comes to glasses, we see "with" them and not "in" them; but reasonable minds may differ on that.)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you mean 3, 4 and 5 don't mean the same as 1 and 2? I thought they all meant the same. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: I agree that they all mean the same, though with a slight difference in emphasis.

Comment: @happy, I did mean that 1/2 were different from 3/4/5, but on second thoughts they are the same. As Kate says, there is a slight difference in emphasis, but it doesn't change the core meaning. CORRECTED.